# Watermarking images with direct direct URL

Tags: media

I have installed image cache actions module to watermark all images shown in my juicebox galleries.
when I access them by following url which is reading from styled folders, it is properly showing the watermarked images

```
http://localhost/drupal/sites/default/files/styles/photo_gallery_resize/public/field/image/design.jpg?itok=MSjmkfIa
```

But unfortunately my original images are still accessible by direct URL without watermarks:

```
http://localhost/drupal/sites/default/files/field/image/design.jpg
```

What can I do to watermark images accessed by direct URL or protect them from being shown.

Comment: Related: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/76502/16495 and http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/3447/16495 Please decide if you want to apply watermark on save, or to keep them and simply restrict answers. Both ways are OK, but we should know what answers you want here. If you must have both ways explained, you can ask two questions.

Comment: .. or some web server level protection to allow imagecache images but deny original files.

Comment: As I understand, those links are talking about restricting the direct URL, I prefer to use imagecache styles for direct URLs too, is there any way to do that? by the way I'm new to drupal and don't still know how to write program for drupal.